# How do I remove corrupted data from .csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, corrupt

So I have lots of data but I'm not sure how I remove the corrupt data.

In the file the list is like this:

```
EMERIE,ESPARZA,166,57,34,BLUE,BLONDE

ADALINE,PARSONS,158,39,£$**),BROWN,GREY
```

The `£$**)` represents corrupted data but I don't know how to remove it, I have over 10,000 names and some of them are like this.

Comment: If you expect a number in that field but you receive letters, then you just need to try the conversion to a number (int32.TryParse) and if not successful discard the line or insert a replacement value

Comment: It doesn't look like CSV is corrupted in terms of format, are you talking about data validation instead?

Comment: I need to discard the 'corrupted' data but it's mixed with over 10,000 other pieces of data, not sure if there is some way to delete all the corrupt data.

Comment: Please, provide the better description for the task you are trying to solve, ideally with code samples to demonstrate the issue. Currently I see the data that fits to CSV file format

Comment: If this is a one-time fixup you could import into Excel, sort by the column with bad data, cut away the bad rows.  If not, you need to write code to validate the field(s) before adding the row.

Comment: Do you want to toss the rows or leave the cells blank?

Comment: Is this part of your program or you are trying to write a script to clean-up the data? It's not possible to say how it needs to be done if we don't know what you are doing

Comment: Sorry guys i am not a professional, I would like to just get rid of the corrupted data if that helps. Anything that would allow me to remove pieces of data that are corrupted (contain £$%*)

Comment: Can you open file in text editor of your choice and then just replace £$%* with empty string? Would that help?

Comment: Not really, I've tried that. It replaces the corrupt data with nothing, If only I could select all the data containing certain characters then delete them I might be ok

Comment: You should specify what the substitute for the *corrupted* needs to be. Also, if the *corruption* can occur in both the numeric fields and the litteral ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to completely remove the corrupted data rows rather than modify them, you could do something like the following:

```
public void RemoveCorruptData()
    {
        string path = @"C:\CSV.txt";
        string newPath = @"C:\new-CSV.txt";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        Regex corrupt = new Regex("£$**");

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!corrupt.IsMatch(line))
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newpath, false))
            {
                foreach (String line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```